# Unable to get user email in google one tap sign-in process

Tags: javascript, web, google-signin, google-oauth

I am integrating google one tap sign in process in my website. I can show the sign in prompt correctly, but I cannot figure it out how to get user email after the login. Can anyone please help me.
reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/reference/js-reference

Answer (score 1):

If HTML API is used, you can get the email from the ID token on you server side. More details at: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/verify-google-id-token

If JavaScript API is used, a CredentialResponse object is passed to the callback function. You can get the ID token from the CredentialResponse object.
More detials at: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/reference/js-reference#CredentialResponse